# No greeter screen on startup (following shutdown) RESOLVED

Tags: greeter

I am on Elementary OS 5.0 Juno.

The new greeter screen worked fine for me when it was recently introduced.

However, recently,when starting the computer from scratch (i.e. after a shutdown), I do not get a greeter screen. It goes straight to the desktop, then I get a message asking me to "Enter password to unlock your login keyring".
If i then enter the password everything is fine.

If I log out (as opposed to shutting down), I do get the greeter as normal.

How can I get my greeter screen back when I switch on the computer following a shutdown?

Thank you

UPDATE: All is working well now, not sure why. All I did was change my password in System Settings, User Accounts, not sure if this is what cured it.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this when you set some user account to "Login automatically". This is an option from System Settings > 
User accounts just above 'change password' button of the account.